# Sort a matrix by columns with index return

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I want to sort all the columns of a matrix A in R.
So far, I am using

```
apply(A,2,sort),
```

which gives sorted columns.

But I would also like to have the indexes of each column after sorting.
I tried to use `index.return=TRUE` as option of `sort`, but I think I can not use it in `apply`. How can I get the indexes?

Comment: do you need this? `apply(A,2,function(x) sort(x, index.return = TRUE))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can also use `index.return = TRUE`, but when we have that, it will return a `list`.

```
lst <-  apply(A,2,sort, index.return = TRUE)
```

If we need to convert it to a 3 column matrix with the column index as well

```
do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, colInd = seq_along(lst),
              lapply(lst, function(x) do.call(cbind, x))))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
A <- matrix(rnorm(25), 5, 5)
```

Comment: Thanks. Easy solution, I tried to put the index.return option in brackets after sort.